# What is mean of messages in logcat

Tags: android

I'm developing an app using google map. I've set everything like intenet permission, api key in xml file, sdk tools for android 2.2 API 8 and emulator also but when we run it we got messages in logCat like this.

> MapActivity couldn't get connection factory client GC_FOR_MALLOC freed
>   1643 objects/214824 bytes in 66ms

And at last map is not displayed. Only grids are shown.

Comment: Please post your proper logcat error message.

Comment: Kindly add the Android Manifest.xml and Map Activity class.